# vk_api, аргументы

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Можно ли с такой конструкцией принимать аргументы у команд и если можно то как?
К примеру есть команда msg, как сделать, чтобы она принимала аргументы к примеру msg [текст], и этот [текст] сохранялся в переменную как аргумент?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import vk_api, random

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
vk = vk_session.get_api()

while True:
    messagess = vk.messages.getConversations(offset=0, count=20, filter= "unread")
    if messagess["count"] >= 1:
        userid = messagess["items"][0]["last_message"]["from_id"]
        body = messagess["items"][0]["last_message"]["text"] 

        if body == "msg [текст]":
            vk.messages.send(peer_id=userid, message="Вы ввели msg [текст]", random_id=random.randint(1, 2147483647))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Способов много, вот некоторые из них:

- Взять срез
- Разделить с помощью функции `split`
- Вернуть группу из регулярного выражения (модуль `re`)

***Пример:***

```py
import re


body = 'msg Hello!'

print(body[4:])                          # Hello!
print(body[body.find(' ') + 1:])         # Hello!
print(body.split()[1])                   # Hello!
print(re.findall(r'msg (.*)', body)[0])  # Hello!
```

*Примечание: Предполагается, что строка уже проверена и точно содержит какой-то текст, это не оптимальные способы, хороший способ я привёл в P. S*

---

Сохранить полученное значение в переменную довольно тривиально (например, для среза):

```py
text = body[4:]
```

***P. S.:***
Я в своём боте использую, примерно, следующую конструкцию:

```
body = 'msg Hello!'

if body.startswith('msg'):
    text = body[4:]
```

Этот пример сработает даже при сообщении без текста (`msg`), в таком случае срез вернёт пустую строку, чего мы и ожидаем.

Comment: а вы можете показть пример? Очень надо ;)

Comment: В ответе жирным шрифом **Пример:**, если он не понятен, задайте новый вопрос, не используйте для комментариев поле для вопросов.